# How can I serialize a base object if the implementing object is not Serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am trying to serialize a type like follows:

```
    public UsersPanel(UsersVM userVm)
    {
        var serialized = Serialize(userVm);
    }

    public static string Serialize(ViewModelBase instance)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, instance); // breaks here
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Where `UsersVM` is defined as

```
public class UsersVm : ViewModelBase {}
```

and `ViewModelBase` is defined as

```
[Serializable]
public class ViewModelBase {}
```

This is giving me the following error:

> Type 'UsersVM' is not marked as serializable.

Why is it telling me this, if I've cast the object `userVm` to `ViewModelBase` (which *is* marked as Serializable) by passing it into `Serialize(ViewModelBase instance)`?

I would have thought that passing `UsersVM` would be replaced by the base type `ViewModelBase` when passing it into the method which takes `ViewModelBase`.

How can I serialize ViewModelBase?

Comment: have you tried casting to the base object when you serialize? eg var serialized = Serialize(userVm as ViewModelBase);

Comment: @Jonathan: Unfortunately BinaryFormatter will still complain because the base class is not marked serializable.

Comment: or just implement ISerializable? Try writing [Serializable] just over your class. If this helps you, I would be glad to provide it as an answer.

Comment: I'm not so sure the question is 'how do i fix it' as much as it is 'why is it happening'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solving the Issue**

You have to mark your derived class as serializable, too

```
[Serializable]
public class UsersVm : ViewModelBase {}
```

**Why you have to do this**

The BinaryFormatter looks at the *actual type* of the object instance when serializing. The cast just tells the compiler to treat the instance *as if* it were a different type but does not actually change the instance into that type.

**Side Note**

*I initially read the question backwards and found the answer to the inverse question interesting and potentially useful to others...*

Note if the situation were reversed (the base class were not marked serializable and you didn't have access to the source code), you could still accomplish your goal.

> the subclass can implement ISerializable, use reflection to read and serialize the base classes' fields, and use reflection again to set these fields during deserialization

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163902.aspx#S14

The article provides a code sample including a utility to help implement this approach.